# Phonegap Android text keypad after numeric keypad

Tags: android, html, cordova, text, input

I have two inputs in a form, first I have this:

```
<input id="mynumber" type="number">
```

then:

```
<input id="myname" type="text">
```

Whenever I focus the text input after having focused the number input, the number keypad apears instead of the text keypad.

Is there a way to force the text keypad on an input? I hate to have to unfocus the text input and then refocus it to make the correct keypad appear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read it appears that only 'number', 'url' and 'email' field types trigger the changing of the keypad.

Though I haven't tested this, you may want to switch your 'text' field to 'email' or 'url' and see if that fits your needs.